# adding slider in magento to cms page

Tags: magento, slider, content-management-system

```
{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="your_bannerslider_id"}}
```

I am trying to add a slider using the above code, to a cms page in Magento.

My banner id is called `mySlider`, so have done:

```
{{block type="bannerslider/default" name="bannerslider.bannerslider" template="bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml" bannerslider_id="mySlider"}}
```

Nothing shows.

I saw that someone recommended setting each banner to the day before it was creating but that didn't work either.

Comment: Which banner extension are you using in magento (version) ?

Comment: its called Banner Slider and is Magento version 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should copy module files to your current template files. So that you have bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml in your templates folder.
Also look if slider is active and with slider content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the banner ID which is the number in the first column in the admin panel (under the section for managing the slider). What you are using now is simply the title.